# I get an error when I install the SWITIFY package, does anyone know what it means?

Tags: python, django

when I install the package sweetify, I get the following error

Does anyone know what the reason is?
I went through all the steps that were in the main dock

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 228, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\sweetify\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .sweetify import *
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\sweetify\sweetify.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .encoder import LazyEncoder
  File "C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\sweetify\encoder.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
ImportError: cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\nahid\PycharmProjects\fitshow\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django/issues/29 this is a known bug and should be fixed in next release. As @Ichojnacki suggests, a solution would be to use an older version of Django

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `sweetify` is not compatible with Django 4.0. See the changelog: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0

> django.utils.encoding.force_text() and smart_text() are removed.

Try with older version of django, I recommend 3.2.13 :)

Answer (score 0):

this error is coming from django v4 . according to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.0/#deprecated-features-3-0)  `django.utils.encoding.force_text()` `and smart_text()` are removed.

**possible solution** :

1 - using Django version 4> add in  `settings.py` :

```
import django
from django.utils.encoding import force_str
django.utils.encoding.force_text = force_str
```

2. Downgrade your django version to django<=3